# One of the two Meteor examples does not work on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, meteor, windows-10

Installed Meteor v1.4.1.2, completed the basic Simple Todos tutorial and wanted to check the two examples mentioned in it:

```
meteor create --example localmarket
meteor create --example todos
```

And Run Todos sample will get error!

```
\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:165
  throw error;
  ^

Error: unexpected eof
at decorate (C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\abstract.js:67:36)
at Extract.Abstract.error (C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\abstract.js:61:12)
at Extract._streamEnd (C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\tar\lib\extract.js:91:35)
at BlockStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:51:8)
at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
at BlockStream.emit (events.js:166:7)
at BlockStream._emitChunk (C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\block-stream\block-stream.js:203:10)
at BlockStream.resume (C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\block-stream\block-stream.js:58:15)
at Extract.Reader.resume (C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\reader.js:242:34)
at Entry.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:261:8)
at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
at Entry.emit (events.js:166:7)
at Entry.resume (C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\tar\lib\entry.js:93:8)
at resume (C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\collect.js:62:16)
at unblockEntry (C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\collect.js:43:28)
at Entry.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\collect.js:47:9)
at FileWriter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\dir-writer.js:146:11)
at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
at FileWriter.emit (events.js:166:7)
at WriteStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\file-writer.js:45:10)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at WriteStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
at C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:214:14
at C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:241:16
at C:\Users\aboo\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:232:16
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above meteor basics examples

```
meteor create --example localmarket
meteor create --example todos
```

are created using meteor older versions . current using meteor version is 1.4

the above examples are created 1.3  .SO need to update the programmes are packages.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor 1.4.1.1 has a bug with Windows 10. You can find a solution for your problem in this issue - https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7703 @ Meteor's GitHub.